# how can I add custom button to outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

how can I add custom button to Outlook send mail form window ?

actually how to achive new mail form window in Application object properties ?

I try NewInspector event with but the event parameter have self inspector but inspector does not have CommandBars object !!

please help
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommandBars were deprecated. You need to use the Fluent UI for creating a custom UI in Outlook. VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the UI in Outlook:

1. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)
2. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)

Note, you can design a custom UI using the designer and then export it into an XML markup. See [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add a ribbon button in the current versions of Outlook is through the [IRibbonExtensibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility?view=office-pia) interface implemented by your COM addin.

VSTO makes it easier, but the underlying mechanism is still the same.